# How to insert information on a word embedding?

Tags: nlp, embedding, word-embedding, transformer-model

I saw that transformers inserted the positional embedding of a word on its word embedding. How can I insert another things like te word size for example? Is it possible to view the internal code of a transformer framework like BERT for example to edit something like that?

Answer (score 0):

It's all open source and [available on GitHub](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L165)—so yes, you can view the internal code. If you have an idea for how to incorporate word length or other features, you're welcome to. It's not something I'd encourage.

Comment: Thank you. I saw some articles that they incorporate the pronuciation and it worked well